# Do timer events in Delphi happen in their own thread?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

When a Delphi timer executes, is it not in the main thread?

```
procedure TMainForm.MyTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
      MyModalDialog.StatusText.BeginUpdate;
      MyModalDialog.StatusText.Text := 'timer fired...';
      MyModalDialog.StatusText.EndUpdate;
end;
```

I am wondering if crashes here are due to updating the GUI elements outside of the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer will execute on the main thread. No need to worry about using Synchronize().

Answer (score 4):

The timer event handler execute in the context of the thread having created it. Usually it is the main thread but you can create a timer within any thread.